# How to show a contact in the browser after getting the ID using the Office 365 REST API

Tags: api, office365

I'm using the Office 365 REST API to look for contacts. Once I have the contact details, I need to open a browser and show it to the user.

So, for example, I find a contact with ID:
AAMkADVlY2IzOGVjLWUwMzgtNGFmMS1iMzZhLTY2MDE0ZTRiNTg4NwBGAAAAAAD1KqAdSTtFQKuI5sWH1n87BwBFsSNh6xuxTYUopw458yHGAAAAAAEOAABFsSNh6xuxTYUopw458yHGAAAAABTzAAA=

And then I'm using the following URL to show it:
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADVlY2IzOGVjLWUwMzgtNGFmMS1iMzZhLTY2MDE0ZTRiNTg4NwBGAAAAAAD1KqAdSTtFQKuI5sWH1n87BwBFsSNh6xuxTYUopw458yHGAAAAAAEOAABFsSNh6xuxTYUopw458yHGAAAAABTzAAA%3D

The browser shows a windows containing some information of the contact, but it's not the same information I have when browsing the Office 365 People app. I just get the name, and there is no way to see all the details or edit this contact. This is a screenshot of what I see when I open that URL:
[image: Limited contact details]

And this is the information I would like to see (available when I use the People app):
[image: Full contact details]

Is there any other way to achieve this? How can I show the contact details to my user?

Any hint will be greatly appreciatted!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple sample application (in Angular, but it's just using REST so you should be able to use it) that uses the Outlook Contacts REST API to get a user's contacts and display them to the user.

In short, you should be able to get the information you want by making a GET request to "https: //outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts" to get all the contacts of the signed in user, or a GET request to "https: //outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/{contact_id}" to get a specific contact. In either case, you must also supply an access token and make sure your application has the correct permissions scope.

View the code (and some links that may be helpful to you as you continue your Office 365 development) on GitHub: https://github.com/martellaj/contacts-api-sample